# Testing some classes in C ++

Tags: c++, class, expression, public, void

I just want to test some classes in a C++ program, but I have an "Expected expression" error in Xcode.

Actually here is the code I wrote :

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class A {
    public :
    virtual void M1 () { cout << " A::M1"; }
    void M2 () { cout << " A::M2"; }
    virtual void M3 () { cout << " A::M3"; }
};


class B : public A {
    public :
    void M1 () { cout << " B::M1"; }
    virtual void M2 () { cout << " B::M2"; }
    void M3 () { cout << " B::M3"; }
};


class C : public B {
    public :
    void M1 () { cout << " C::M1"; }
    void M2 () { cout << " C::M2"; }
    void M3 () { cout << " C::M3"; }
};


class D {
    public :
    D (A v, A& r, B& s) : va (v), ra (r), rb (s) { }
    void M1 () { cout << " D::M1 -->"; va.M1 (); ra.M1 (); rb.M1 (); cout << ’\n’; }
    void M2 () { cout << " D::M2 -->"; va.M2 (); ra.M2 (); rb.M2 (); cout << ’\n’; }
    void M3 () { cout << " D::M3 -->"; va.M3 (); ra.M3 (); rb.M3 (); cout << ’\n’; }
    protected :
    A va; A& ra; B& rb;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

A a; B b; C c; D d1 (a, a, b); D d2 (a, b, c); D d3 (a, c, b); D d4 (b, c, c);
cout << "avec d1 :\n"; d1.M1 (); d1.M2 (); d1.M3 ();
cout << "avec d2 :\n"; d2.M1 (); d2.M2 (); d2.M3 ();
cout << "avec d3 :\n"; d3.M1 (); d3.M2 (); d3.M3 ();
cout << "avec d4 :\n"; d4.M1 (); d4.M2 (); d4.M3 ();

return 0;
```

}

I really do not know where that error came from.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Surely the error message came with a line number.

Comment: in which line does the error come?

Comment: In Class D, the 3 void lines (M1, M2 & M3)

Comment: That is perfect Jesse. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's the single quotes used `’\n’`. Please change them to `'\n'`.

Comment: actually I'd go with "\n"

Comment: Yes, I've just tested. Do it with "\n"

Comment: @stevejpurves: Why would you change from a `char` to a char array?

Comment: Exactly, I just changed it into '\n' and it worked. Actually I do not even know where that kind of single quotes came from. That is weird

Comment: @Jesse in this piece of code, just consistency. Double quotes are used throughout, but I see your point; \n is a single char. endl as mentioned is probably better them both though.

Comment: @stevejpurves - `endl` is only better if it provides the semantics that the class requires. It's more than a newline; it also flushes the output buffer. That can kill performance.

Answer (score 1):

replace all (`’`) for (`"`):

```
void M1 () { cout << " D::M1 -->"; va.M1 (); ra.M1 (); rb.M1 (); cout << ’\n’; }
void M2 () { cout << " D::M2 -->"; va.M2 (); ra.M2 (); rb.M2 (); cout << ’\n’; }
void M3 () { cout << " D::M3 -->"; va.M3 (); ra.M3 (); rb.M3 (); cout << ’\n’; }
```

becomes:

```
void M1 () { cout << " D::M1 -->"; va.M1 (); ra.M1 (); rb.M1 (); cout << "\n"; }
void M2 () { cout << " D::M2 -->"; va.M2 (); ra.M2 (); rb.M2 (); cout << "\n"; }
void M3 () { cout << " D::M3 -->"; va.M3 (); ra.M3 (); rb.M3 (); cout << "\n"; }
```

or also consider using endl which will flush the stream if it is buffered:

```
void M1 () { cout << " D::M1 -->"; va.M1 (); ra.M1 (); rb.M1 (); cout << endl; }
void M2 () { cout << " D::M2 -->"; va.M2 (); ra.M2 (); rb.M2 (); cout << endl; }
void M3 () { cout << " D::M3 -->"; va.M3 (); ra.M3 (); rb.M3 (); cout << endl; }
```